# Combing two arrays in ascending order with unknown values inside the array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have managed to create both arrays, however I can't figure out how to combine the two arrays. Every tutorial I see merges them as such:

```
int[] arr1 = {3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9};
int[] arr2 = {3, 4, 5, 6};
// Output: 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9
```

What I need is something that would output: 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9
Here is the code I have written so far:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Merger {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr1 = new int[10000];

        int[] arr2 = new int[10000];
        int[] merged = new int[20000];
        int a1 = 0;
        int a2 = 0;
        int size = -1;
        int size2 = -1;
        int sizecheck = 0;
        int size2check = 0;
        System.out
                .println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10,000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            arr1[i] = scan.nextInt();
            merged[i] = arr1[i];
            if (arr1[i] <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (size <= arr1[i]) {
                size = arr1[i];
                sizecheck++;
            }
            a1++;
        }
        System.out
                .println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10,000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            arr2[i] = scan.nextInt();
            merged[i + a1] = arr2[i];
            if (arr2[i] <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (size2 <= arr2[i]) {
                size2 = arr2[i];
                size2check++;
            }
            a2++;
        }
        System.out.println("First Array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a1; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + arr1[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\nSecond Array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a2; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + arr2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints both arrays out, however does not combine and sort the two.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code ! There may be a faster/easier way to do it but this one works as long as the 2 arrays are sorted

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3, 5};
    int[] a2 = {1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5};
    int[] a3 = merge(a1, a2);
    for (int i : a3) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}

public static int[] merge(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    int[] a3 = new int[a1.length + a2.length];
    int indexA1 = 0;
    int indexA2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a3.length; i++) {
        int n;
        if (indexA1 == a1.length && indexA2 < a2.length) {
            n = a2[indexA2];
            indexA2++;
        } else if (indexA1 < a1.length && indexA2 == a2.length) {
            n = a1[indexA1];
            indexA1++;
        } else {
            if (a1[indexA1] < a2[indexA2]) {
                n = a1[indexA1];
                indexA1++;
            } else {
                n = a2[indexA2];
                indexA2++;
            }
        }
        a3[i] = n;
    }
    return a3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not yet familiar with Streams, but I would like to give you an example of what you can do with them.

Add import

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
```

Add this at the end of your main method

```
System.out.println(""); 
IntStream arr1Stream = IntStream.of(arr1).limit(a1); //creates an InStream with the first a1 values of arr1
IntStream arr2Stream = IntStream.of(arr2).limit(a2); 
int[] both = IntStream.concat(arr1Stream, arr2Stream).sorted().toArray(); //combines the two streams, sorts them an converts them to an Array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(both)); //easy way to print an array
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a Stream.

```
int[] arr1 = {3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9};
int[] arr2 = {3, 4, 5, 6};
```

- Stream both arrays.
- flatMap them to a single IntStream
- sort them
- convert to an array

```
int [] combined = Stream.of(arr1,arr2)
                       .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
                       .sorted()
                       .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combined));
```

Prints

```
[3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9]
```

A non-stream approach can be done as follows:

```
// increase arr1 to make room for arr2
int oldLen = arr1.length;
arr1 = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length+arr2.length);

// copy arr2 starting at 0, to arr1 starting at the old length
// positon of arr1 for a length of arr2
System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, arr1, oldLen, arr2.length);

// sort and print
Arrays.sort(arr1);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
```

Prints

```
[3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9]
```

Although your question, as asked, said nothing about `merging` sorted arrays, here is how you would do it.

The algorithm is simple.  Just iterate thru each array and compare current values.

- if `arr1[i] <= arr2[k]`, copy `arr1[i] to result`, advance `i` by `1`
- else copy  `arr2[k] to result`, advance `k` by `1`.
- in all cases the index to result, `r`,  is advanced by `1`

```
public int[] merge(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    // result array
    int[] result = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];

    int r = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // Iterate thru the arrays, copying the lowest or equal value
    // to the target array.  This process will cease when one of the arrays
    // has been fully processed.


    for (; i < arr1.length && k < arr2.length; ) {
        for (; k < arr2.length && i < arr1.length;) {
            if (arr1[i] <= arr2[k]) {
                result[r++] = arr1[i++]; 
            }else {
                 result[r++] = arr2[k++];
            }               
        }
    }
```

Having reached this far in the algorithm, one of the arrays must have been completely processed.  So try and copy both. For the empty array, the `while loop` basically acts like an if statement.

```
    while (i < arr1.length) {
        result[r++] = arr1[i++]; 
    }
    while (k < arr2.length) {
        result[r++] = arr2[k++]; 
    }
    // return the result
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Merger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = { 3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
        int[] arr2 = { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] res = merge(arr1, arr2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int[] res = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];

        for (int i = 0, a1 = 0, a2 = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            if (a1 == arr1.length)
                res[i] = arr2[a2++];
            else if (a2 == arr2.length)
                res[i] = arr1[a1++];
            else
                res[i] = arr1[a1] <= arr2[a2] ? arr1[a1++] : arr2[a2++];
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be written using the classes, [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and [`System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html).

**Steps:**

1. Copy elements of `arr1[]` into a new array (say, `output[]`) whose size is the sum of the sizes of the given arrays.
2. Copy the elements of `arr2[]`, after the element of `arr1[]`, into `output[]`
3. Sort `output[]`

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = { 3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
        int[] arr2 = { 3, 4, 5, 6 };

        // Copy elements of arr1[] into a new array whose size is the sum of the sizes
        // of the given arrays
        int[] output = Arrays.copyOf(arr1, arr1.length + arr2.length);

        // Copy the elements of arr2[], after the element of arr1[], into output[]
        System.arraycopy(arr2.clone(), 0, output, arr1.length, arr2.length);

        // Sort output[]
        Arrays.sort(output);

        // Display output[]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) method for this purpose:

```java
int[] arr1 = {3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9};
int[] arr2 = {3, 4, 5, 6};

// create a new array of total length
int[] arr3 = new int[arr1.length + arr2.length];

// copy first array to the beginning of the total array
System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr3, 0, arr1.length);
// copy second array to the end of the total array
System.arraycopy(arr2, 0, arr3, arr1.length, arr2.length);

// sort the total array
Arrays.sort(arr3);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3));
// [3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9]
```